# Why is the Random Value node output not accepted by the Cube node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

As you can see in the picture, for some reason the vector data generated by the *Random Value* node is not being accepted by the *Cube* node.

Right below, I show that if the vector is generated by a straight *Vector* node, it is accepted.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Try to put an integer value into the input "ID".

Comment: So not even adding an ID node solves the thing: you MUST add an integer to the ID field. I don't think this is intuitive or functional with the UI. Needs refinement imo.

Comment: It's just misunderstanding what the _Random Value Node_ does. Quoting from manual: "The Random Value node outputs a white noise like value as a Float, Integer, Vector, or Boolean **field**." The output will always give multiple random values to use in other data fields. The _Cube_ node produces a **single** cube - not **multiple** cubes. Instancing the cube via e.g. _Instance on Points_ you get multiple instances on which you can use multiple random values. The ID input is used to pick a single random value derived from both, the ID **and** the seed, and outputs this single value as a field.

Comment: Another thing on understanding the node design: a diamond shaped output socket will give fields as output, a circular input socket will **only** accept single values, **never** fields. Some diamond shaped inputs accept fields and single values, and if the complete chain of connections only consists of single values, the diamond shape turns into a circular shape. But whenever a node has a circular shape in its default, unconnected form, you cannot enter fields as input.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!